# JQuery.html($sce.trustAsHtml("<br>loltest")) not working

Tags: angularjs

Here're video examples of what's happening:

Without sanitizing,
https://i.lithi.io/6GLS.mp4

With Sanitizing 
https://i.lithi.io/TVIu.mp4

When clicked, this is supposed to make the text above, render the full text.

To do this, I have created a function

```
$scope.loadMore = function($event)
{
    var element = $($event.currentTarget);

    //console.log(element.data('text'));
    var text = $scope.toHtml(element.data('text'));//$compile(element.data('text'));
    //$sce.trustAsHtml(element.data('text'))
    console.log(text);
    if (element.parent().find('#text_data').length) {
        element.parent().find('#text_data').html(text);
    } else {
        /*element.parent().find('#text_data').html(
            element.data('text').length > 100  ?
            element.data('text').substring(0, 100)
            :
            element.data('text')
        );*/
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function with ng-click. Basically it gets the parent, and then selects the element with the text inside.

The button has a Data Attribution with the full length text (not limited to 100 chars).

When I sanitize it inputs blank text? Whereas if I don't sanitize, it inputs the text.

I don't know if it's the right way to actually do it, but I just replaced the 
tag with `\n` in my PHP, now it doesn't render them. Since YouTube doesn't support other HTML, it should be fine.

Comment: please show the `element.data('text')` does it have `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: @naveen here's a printscreen of the outputted text: 
https://i.lithi.io/40pS.png

Comment: Please use the Stack Snippet functionality, or a site like plunkr or jsFiddle, to illustrate the problem. Include text as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your HTML is encoded. You have to decode it like this before displaying.

```
//angular hack to html decode
let decoded = angular.element('<div />').html(data).text()
$scope.decodedData = $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
```

There is nothing like `$scope.toHtml(data)`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/54mzkjqe/

Comment: Sorry, I created a function 
```
$scope.toHtml = function(data)
{
return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
}
```
^Not copied from my code, just typed it, but i think thats right.